# How do I add name value data to an android HTTP file upload POST request

Tags: php, android, post, file-upload, httprequest

I have an android photo upload script that uploads fine if I use $_GET to read some data, I want to use all $_POST. The problem is I need to append data do the posted request to include basic name value pairs along with the file upload. I can get this to work if I have the server use $_GET and just add the extra data in the url string, but I want to use post. Is there a way to encode other post data in the file upload that the server can read using $_POST. Heres the function, notice the URL string where, I'm trying to get the variables api_key,session_key, and method to be sent in the POST request.

```
public void uploadPhoto(FileInputStream fileInputStream, String sessionKey) throws IOException, ClientProtocolException {

    URL connectURL = new URL(API_URL +"?api_key=" +API_KEY+ "&session_key=" + sessionKey + "&method=" + ApiMethods.UPLOAD_PHOTO); //server ignores this data

    String lineEnd = "\r\n";
    String twoHyphens = "--";
    String boundary = "*****";

    HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) connectURL.openConnection();

    // Allow Inputs
    conn.setDoInput(true);

    // Allow Outputs
    conn.setDoOutput(true);

    // Don't use a cached copy.
    conn.setUseCaches(false);

    // Use a post method.
    conn.setRequestMethod("POST");

    conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");

    conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data;boundary="+ boundary);

    DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());

    dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
    dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"uploadedfile\";filename=\""+ "file.png" + "\"" + lineEnd);
    dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);


    // create a buffer of maximum size

    int bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
    int maxBufferSize = 1028;
    int bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
    byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

    // read file and write it into form...

    int bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
    while (bytesRead > 0) {
        dos.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
        bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
        bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
        bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
        /*
         * dos.writeBytes(lineEnd); dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary +
         * twoHyphens + lineEnd);
         */
    }

    // send multipart form data necesssary after file data...
    dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
    dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd);
    dos.flush();
    // Log.d(TAG, "  dos5: " + dos.toString());
    InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();
    // retrieve the response from server
    int ch;

    StringBuffer b = new StringBuffer();
    while ((ch = is.read()) != -1) {
        b.append((char) ch);
    }
    String s = b.toString();
    dos.close();

}
```

EDIT
I'm thinking something like the following is needed for each added param

```
    dos.writeBytes("--" + boundary + lineEnd);
    dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data;name=api_key=" + lineEnd + lineEnd + API_KEY);
    dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
    dos.writeBytes("--" + boundary + "--" + lineEnd);
```

Answer (score 0):

There are some existing open libraries that support mime encoding which might save you some time. I used the code from here in some stuff I hacked up for posting:

http://www.softwarepassion.com/android-series-get-post-and-multipart-post-requests/

You can get the apache-mime4j and httpmime libraries from here:

http://code.google.com/p/osmdroid/source/browse/trunk/osmdroid-google-wrapper/lib/?r=769

Comment: Note: You can save lots of space in your apk by including copies of the multipart classes from AOSP rather than the apache libs: http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/frameworks/base.git;a=tree;f=core/java/com/android/internal/http/multipart;h=7256a2afc68c0ae712c4114c9dec50333ae9875c;hb=HEAD

Comment: Thanks for the pointer! Haven't dug into the Android Open Source Project yet, great to know the resources are available.

Comment: @nEx.Software Can you point me to a tutorial which shows how can I import and use the MultiPart classes without importing the ones downloadable from Apache's website?

Comment: @codebreaker Here's something I put together a while back... https://github.com/MobiDevelop/android-samples/tree/master/post-image

Comment: @nEx.Software +1 You know you should post it separately..I guess post in a question and answer it; MODs should sticky it :)

Comment: @nEx.Software Do you have a sample/any pointers on how can I send a zip file from my app (on Android) over to a IIS server(server side; currently tried using C#.NET) Currently I am able to transfer a *.zip file over to the server but when I open it using winrar/7zip it says that the archive is corrupted..I guess the headers are being written while stream-reading and saving the zip file at the server side :(